# How to access all elements of a list (composed of dictionaries)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have two variables that are lists composed of dictionaries; a and b which will always have same number of elements.

For 3d graphing I create another dictionary from them. When I know the amount of elements this code words fine; say example I know there are 3.

```
fig = dict( data=[a[0],a[1],a[2],b[0],b[1],b[2]], layout=layout )
```

The problem is I in general will not know how many elements are in a and b. I cannot seem to figure out how to correctly iterate or loop through to replicate the code above in the general case.

The goal is to replicate the code above for the general case where I do not know the number of elements in a and b.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
fig = dict(data=a + b, layout=layout)
```

The `+` operator will concatenate the operands when used between two lists.

For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a + b 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
fig = dict( data=a + b, layout=layout )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain both lists. It is more time efficient than creating of a new list by concatenating:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

for i in chain(a, b):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```